# Progress Dialog in React-native BottomTab navigator

Tags: react-native

I am using react-native createbottomtab navigator to my app. Here i have 4 Tabs, 1.Home, 2.Profile 3.Sync and 4.Settings. Here i showed the alert box for while click the Sync tab. Other than Sync tab i used the screen(class component). But in Sync i don't want to navigate to screen so i used function here i need to show the progress dialog for click the Sync Alert ok button. But i am facing the issue for in function i can't use the Progress dialog. Any one can help me how to do this in react-native with bottomtab.

```js
// SyncScreen.js 
import { Alert } from 'react-native';

export default function SyncScreen() {
  Alert.alert("Information", "Do you want to Sync ", [
    {
      text: "Cancel",
      onPress: () => {
        console.log("Cancel Pressed");
      }
    },
    {
      text: "OK",
      onPress: () => {
        //Here i need to show the progress bar
      }
    }
  ]);
}
```

```js
export default const LoggedInNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack
    },
    Sync: {
      screen: () => null,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Sync",
        tabBarOnPress: () => {
          {
            SyncScreen();
          }
        }
      }
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Setting"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: "#0A3D6A",
        inactiveTintColor: "gray"
      }
    })
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you please add some code snippets and maybe a gif with your problem?

Comment: Does the alert show on when pressing the Sync button?

Comment: yes. alert shows

Answer (score 0):

The only idea that comes in mind to solve your problem is to navigate to SyncScreen and when the progress bar is complete navigate back.

Something like this:

```js
// SyncScreen.js 
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import * as Progress from 'react-native-progress';


export default function SyncScreen({navigation}) {

  const [progressBarValue, setProgressBarValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (progressBarValue >== 1) {
      // full progressBar, goBack to privious screen
      navigation.navigate.goBack();
    }
  }, [progressBarValue])

  useEffect(() => {
    Alert.alert("Information", "Do you want to Sync ", [
    {
      text: "Cancel",
      onPress: () => {
        console.log("Cancel Pressed");
        navigation.navigate.goBack();
      }
    },
    {
      text: "OK",
      onPress: () => {
        setProgressBarValue(0)
        setInterval(() => {
          setProgressBarValue(prevValue => prevValue + 0.1)
        }, 500);
      }
    }
  ]);
  }, [])


  return null !== progressBarValue ? <Progress.Bar progress={progressBarValue} width={200} /> : null;
}
```

```js
export default const LoggedInNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeStack
    },
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileStack
    },
    Sync: {
      screen: () => SyncScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Sync"
      }
    },
    Settings: {
      screen: SettingsStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Setting"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: "#0A3D6A",
        inactiveTintColor: "gray"
      }
    })
  }
);
```

Comment: It should be adjusted to your needs. Try implementing it and see